# Dependency injection and caching classes best practice

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a project where I want to use caching for several interfaces.

What is the best approach for this? I have two in mind:

1. Both cached and non-cached class will implement the same interface

   ```
   public interface IFoo
   {
       object Get();
   }

   public class Foo : IFoo
   {
       public object Get()
       {
           // return something from datasource
           return null;
       }
   }

   public class FooCached : IFoo
   {
       private readonly IFoo fooService;

       public FooCached(IFoo fooService)
       {
           this.fooService = fooService;
       }

       public object Get()
       {
           // check cache and if empty load the value using fooService (Foo class) 
           return this.fooService.Get();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Each implementation will have its own interface (although in this case it would basically be the same one just with different name)

   ```
   public interface IFoo
   {
       object Get();
   }

   public interface IFooCached : IFoo
   {
   }

   public class Foo : IFoo
   {
       public object Get()
       {
           // return something from datasource
           return null;
       }
   }

   public class FooCached : IFooCached
   {
       private readonly IFoo fooService;

       public FooCached(IFoo fooService)
       {
           this.fooService = fooService;
       }

       public object Get()
       {
           // check cache and if empty load the value using fooService (Foo class) 
           return this.fooService.Get();
       }
   }
   ```

I personally like the first approach more. I don't really like the interface inheritance in this case, and since both these classes are basically the same just with slightly different implementation, I feel like they should have the same interface.

However, since there is no "easy" way I can see to achieve this using Unity, I'm not sure if this really is the best approach. 
Basically I need to resolve IFoo to FooCached everywhere except FooCached itself, where I need Foo. (I know how I could make this work, using for example named registration and specifying InjectionConstructor for FooCached, but this is probably outside the scope of this question). 
The second one, on the other hand, is very easy to setup.

Comment: This question is primarily opinion-based (or more on point, it is requirements based), which makes it [off-topic on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Furthermore, it is miscategorized as dependency-injection, which doesn't apply here - this is a purely design-patterns based question. A DI container is not a cache despite the fact that it may use one to implement some of its lifestyle behavior.

Comment: You should use the first approach and do a Google search for "Unity decorator pattern". You'll find several blog posts and Stackoverflow answers showing how to register decorators with Unity.

Comment: When you start having multiple implementations for the same interface (as in your first approach which is the correct one), DI container begin to be in the way IMO. See [this article](http://criticalsoftwareblog.com/index.php/2015/08/23/why-di-containers-fail-with-complex-object-graphs/.) for more details. The alternative is [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first approach is rather common and is easily integrated with modern DI frameworks, like e.g. `SimpleInjector` (it has `RegisterDecorator` method exactly for this). The pattern is called Decorator and comes in very handy because your caller classes do not need to worry where and how the data comes from, but you configure everything directly in the DI container. I would suggest using the same pattern even without DI, it adheres to open/closed principle as well: this class is closed for modification, but open for extension (by chaining the decorators).

P.S. I am not 100% sure on how this can be achieved with Unity, but you can try searching for the decorator pattern implementation in there.

Comment: Thanks all, this is what I was looking for :)

Comment: You are welcome :)